# How to use portletPreferences

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

i'm trying to get the portletPreferences enter in my ConfigActionImpl which is like this :

```
public void processAction(PortletConfig arg0, ActionRequest arg1,
            ActionResponse arg2) throws Exception {
    String portletResource = ParamUtil.getString(arg1, "portletResource"); 
    final String newlink= ParamUtil.getString(arg1, "newlink");
    final PortletPreferences portletPreferences = 
    PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletSetup(arg1, portletResource);
    portletPreferences.setValue("newlink", newlink);
    portletPreferences.store();        
    SessionMessages.add(arg1, arg0.getPortletName() + ".doConfigure");
}
```

I want to have default preferences display in the first load, and change it if i want.

I was thinking it is like this:

```
protected String showView(ModelMap model, PortletRequest request) {
    preferences.getValue("newlink", monUrl);
}
```

this is the only part of my portlet which don't work, and when i wrote the url directly, the url is well load.

And then, i use monUrl in the code.
I have a null pointer exception

I don't know very much portletPreferences and found nothing can help me.

I just want to load preferences in my variable and use it after.

Comment: Have you tried to get the portetPreferences in the `processAction()` this way: `portletPreferences = arg1.getPreferences()`?

Comment: I am just wondering why you are using `PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletSetup()` since I have never seen one using it. Anyway, how do you know that the preference is actually saved? I mean, where else you retrieve it except for `showView()`?

Comment: Great! However, the best thing to do when you encounter the answer to your own question is to post it as an answer and accept it, not to put the solution in the question itself.

Comment: Ok, i'll do it; Newbie in stackoverflow, my bad. Can't acceept my own fix before 2 days, but it works ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found on my own how to fix it.

In fact i replaced in showView this "PortletRequest request" by this "PortletPreferences preferences"

and this "preferences.getValue("newlink", monUrl);" by "monUrl preferences.getValue("newlink", monUrl);"

```
    protected String showView(ModelMap model, PortletPreferences preferences) {


            monUrl = preferences.getValue("newlink", monUrl);   

}
```

And it works fine.